# Adding external video source to RPi Cam Web Interface

Tags: camera, streaming-video, streaming, web-interface, webrtc

I am using RPi Cam Web Interface to stream raspberry pi camera over browser. But I need to integrate a Wi-Fi camera as well, which produces rtsp or http output. I want to know if the RPi Cam Web Interface has any inbuilt support for external video coming from a WiFi camera, or if there is any hack available for this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, Samrat! Can you be a bit more specific - which WiFi Camera are you looking at and which part of connecting it up are you curious about?

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to integrate wifi based ip cameras, what I found is, most of the wifi camera are giving output as http or rtsp. So i just wanted to know if RPi Cam Web interface, supports external video from a http or rtsp stream.

Comment: I have edited your question to make this more clear

Comment: What "RPi Cam Web interface" are you referring to?

Comment: http://elinux.org/RPi-Cam-Web-Interface this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Rpi Cam Web Interface` cannot do that. [UV4L](http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/sections/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=14) can do what you want. Not only it can live stream the native or an USB camera to any browser via `WebRTC` thanks to the `Rpi` camera or `UVC` drivers, but can also create a virtual device from an external source like IP camera thanks to the `MJPEGStream` driver. You can also have both streaming at the same time as the [Streaming Server](http://www.linux-projects.org/downloads/screenshots/index.png) can be per-device. Audio is also supported. No configuration is required.

Comment: what i found, raspimjpeg is used for creating stream of pics for RPi Cam Web Interface, if we can do to alter the input of raspimjpeg, providing output of ffmpeg (it will be listening to some stream) through some pipe, and utilize it. is there any similar way to do it? also in RPi Cam Web Interface wiki, i had seen about some ispy connect, which they had written for achieving the same